# Find a Bank account by entering accountnumber

Tags: java, list, generics, collections

In 2 days I have an assignment for coding due and I simply can´t get a solution for my task.

The task: Prior we have written our own linked data structure. Now we should implement generics to save different objects in this structure (in our example a bank, with account, accountholder, registry).

We are not allowed to use any methods from java.util. We are only allowed to use java.io and java.lang.

I struggle with finding a way of searching my list.

For example this code:

```
class Account {

int accountNumber;
int bankCode;
int balance;

 Account(int bankCode, int accountNumber) {
    this.bankCode = bankCode;
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    this.balance = 1000;
}
```

I want to find the account by searching with int accountNumber as parameter.
I tried using a foreach loop, however for  my custom list it is not applicable.
Here is the basic desgin of the custom list:

```
class List<L> {
ListCell<L> first = null;

(methods like add ... )
class ListCell<L> {

ListCell<L> next = null;
L content = null;

ListCell(L content, ListCell<L> next) {
this.content = content;
this.next = next;

 }
}
```

I tried this but got the above mentioned error:

```
<L> boolean contains (L l, List<L> list) {
for (L m : list) if (m.equals(l)) return true;
return false;
}
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 2):

In order to use a "forEach" loop in Java, the collection must implement `java.lang.Iterable` and be prepared to return an `Iterator`.  Since you have apparently not implemented any iteration methods you will have to do it "manually", as in

```
for (L p=first; p!=null; p=p.next)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPD**: As correctly stated in the comments, `Iterator`'s package is `java.util`, so if you're not allowed to implement interfaces of this package too, use the loop iteration.

---

In order to be able to use the foreach construct, one has to implement [`Iterable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface for the class. It should provide an [`Iterator<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) with the corresponding `iterator()` method.

Writing an `Iterator<T>` implementation for your `List<L>` is rather simple, it should reference a `ListCell<T>`. Then, on `hasNext()` call it should return true if and only if the `next` is present, and on `next()` call it should move forward, returning the item stored in `next`:

```
class ListCellIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    private ListCell<T> next;

    public ListCellIterator(ListCell<T> next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return next != null;
    }

    @Override 
    public T next() {
        T result = next.content;
        next = next.next;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then you would add `Iterable<T>` interface to `List<L>` and just create a `ListCellIterator<T>` pointing at the first node in your `iterator()` method:

```
class List<L> implements Iterable<L> {

    @Override
    public Iterator<L> iterator() {
        return new ListCellIterator<>(first);
    }

    //...
}
```

This will let you use foreach loop on your `List<L>`:

```
List<Account> accounts = new List<>();

//...
for (Account a: accounts) {
    System.out.println(a.accountNumber);
}
```

---

Otherwise, searching for an item in your `List<L>` can be done with a traditional loop:

```
//it is better to make this a member method of List<L>

public boolean contains (L l) {
    ListCell<L> next = first;
    while (next != null) {
        if (next.content == null ? l == null : next.content.equals(l)) {
            return true;
        }
        next = next.next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `Iterator`'s package is... `java.util`, which is forbidden acccording to the requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped me a bit! I understand that we learn how to write this preimplemented methods by ourselves but it´s really time consuming, especially for a newbie like me...